# Is there a get__display() equivalent for ManyToManyField in models for Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying my usual way of getting more human friendly output by using `get_XX_display()` where XX is the field in question. This normally works for CharFields but I'm now moving to using `ManyToManyField` but I cannot get the same response. How could I parse the options in a 'nice' way even though I may have multiple options, I simply want the text part.

I use this for displaying my checkboxes, so my options are usually of the following form:

```
MY_CHOICES = (
    ('_LS','A'),
    ('_HS','B'),
    ('_SS','C'),
    ('_NS','D'),
    ('_ES','E'),
)
```

So I'd like to say return 'A' if that option has been selected or 'A' 'B' if those two have been selected. I can get values with say: `.values_list()` but cannot get just the human readable text, not the '_LS' etc etc. Is there a smart way to get it out without looping through and concatenating the string.

The model is:

```
class M(models.Model):
    MyFID                  = models.ForeignKey(A)
    MyManyField            = models.ManyToManyField(Choices)


class Choices(models.Model):
    slug = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=32)
    title = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=64)
    def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

Comment: Please post more of your code, most importantly your models

Comment: `ManyToManyField` takes model name not choices, show us your actual code.

Comment: Why are you defining `__str__()` instead of `__unicode__()`?

Comment: @Ignacio: `__str__` is correct in Python 3.x

Comment: @SteinarLima: Nothing in the question proves that 3.x is in use.

Comment: @Rohan, Sorry I was doing from memory as I was away from machine with code on.

Comment: @sk1p I have included more....thanks